# Access WCF method from browser URL

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, rest, web-config

I have a WCF service which works ok when I consume it using a client (written in c#,vb,etc...).
Is there a way to access the service methods using the browser url in addidtion?
I've tried to change the web config using all the samples I found in the internet but with no luck,I guess i'm missing something.

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IJobsService
<OperationContract()> <WebGet()>
Function Test() As String
```

I have in the same class dataContract which has class JobsTool that call all the methods:

```
<DataContract()>
    Public Class JobsTool
      Shared Function Test() As String
          Return "Test function is OK."
      End Function
```

there is another class-JobsService which call the method from the BL:

```
Public Function Test() As String Implements IJobsService.Test
    Return BL.JobsTool.Test()
End Function
```

My web config looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="214748" executionTimeout="999" />
  </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />    
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use restful to reach the goal. 
Here is a simple example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: Followed the link,get an error message while trying to call the method:Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/webhttpbinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: I  get a blank page after this configuration:`<service name="WcfJobsService.JobsService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract ="WcfJobsService.IJobsService" behaviorConfiguration="web">`

Comment: `<behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>`

Comment: It's claiming for a binding named "webHttpBinding", do you have a binding with this name?

Comment: `<ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode:=AddressFilterMode.Any)>
Public Class JobsService
    Implements IJobsService` 'get the following error:<Text xml:lang="he-IL">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).'

Comment: without it,get the following error:without it,get the following error:The message with To 'http://localhost:1419/JobsService.svc/test' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

Comment: I think you're missing to include the webHttp in your behavior.
Check if you have the tag <webHttp/> in your inside the <behavior name=""...>  tag